# Import data from BigQuery to a SQL Server DB

Tags: python, sql, ssis, google-bigquery, data-warehouse

In the company I work for we have a supplier that stores information in Google Big Query from a chatbot that we hire from that supplier. We need to build analysis on these metrics for using chatbots. We have a Data Warehouse and we want to migrate this data to our DW. What is the best way to do this data movement by batch with Integration Services or another tool like Python?

Comment: I think this is too broad a question to get a useful answer. I, personally, would always use an ETL tool but if you already have experienced Python resources and no SSIS resources, for example, then Python would probably be a better solution for you. What tool are you using to load your DW currently and why wouldn't you just continue to use that for this new source?

Comment: Currently i am using SSIS and Pentaho, but i dont know if there is a way to conect SSIS and BQ directly. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area so someone else may have a better answer, but I can think of 3 ways of connecting SSIS and BQ: 1) SSIS doesn't have a native BQ connector but there are connectors available from 3rd parties 2) You can use ODBC/JDBC connections 3) You can use a REST API connection. Which solution you use is probably down to your existing architecture/experience, cost and performance